# python BaseHTTPRequestHandler returning json bad string

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, get

I have a simple http server like so:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("{\"result\": 200}", "utf-8"))

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("{\"result\": 200}", "utf-8"))


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8000):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print("Starting http server on port " + str(port))
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

When I make a GET request, I expect the json: `{result: 200}`, but instead I get `bad string`. What can I do to fix this? I've seen other examples where you can write python objects as json, but not really sure how to put it into this code.

Comment: When I run your code, I get `{result: 200}`. Can you shorten your code to be the simplest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error? See [mcve].

Comment: Just found out the problem. `"{result: 200}"` should be `"{\"result\": 200}"`

Comment: if you're interested, I've edited the question to show me complete program